# Capture output from multiple processes asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, redirectstandardoutput

I have a windows forms app that launches up to X number of console processes concurrently.  I'm taking the JSON output (one object) from each and parsing it for statistics.  I'm keeping track of how many processes I've started and capture their output in `OutputDataReceived()`.  I append the output into a `ConcurrentBag<object>` using the process Id as a key.

Every so often, my JSON ends up as two objects which throws a parsing error.  I'm not sure how I end up with data from two different processes in the same object.  It's as if the `OutputDataReceived()` event is getting data from a different process than the Id it is reporting.  I tried implementing some locking without any luck (it's a bit new to me as I come from a Classic VB background).

Here's some relevant code:

```
private object _lockObj = new object();
private ConcurrentBag<ProcData> _procDatas;

// This is called up to X times
private void LaunchProc(int itemId)
{
    var proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    proc.Exited += proc_Exited;
    proc.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;
    proc.ErrorDataReceived += proc_ErrorDataReceived;
    proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "someapp.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/id=" + itemId;
    proc.Start();

    proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
}

// I assume I'm screwing something up here since this is the only place where I set OutputData
void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var proc = sender as System.Diagnostics.Process;

    if (proc == null) return;
    if (e.Data == null) return;

    lock (_lockObj)
    {
        var item = _procDatas.FirstOrDefault(pi => pi.Id == proc.Id);
        if (item == null)
            _procDatas.Add(new ProcData() {Id = proc.Id, OutputData = e.Data});
        else
            item.OutputData += e.Data;
    }
}

void proc_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var proc = sender as System.Diagnostics.Process;
    ProcMessage procMsg = null;
    lock (_lockObj)
    {
        var procInfo = _procDatas.FirstOrDefault(pi => pi.Id == proc.Id);
        // JSON is parsed here and error is thrown because of multiple objects (eg {"ProcessId":1,"Msg":"Success"}{"ProcessId":2,"Msg":"Success"})
        procMsg = new ProcMessage(procInfo.OutputData);
    }
}

public class ProcData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OutputData { get; set; }
    public string ErrorData { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help resolving this issue or suggesting a different (better) approach.

Comment: The [ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of a Process [can get reused](https://superuser.com/questions/636497/does-windows-7-reuse-process-ids).  Is there any chance that the processes you create initially have exited by the time you create your later processes?  If so, and you are indexing on process id, this might happen.

Comment: Why are you using separate processes, rather than threads in the same process?

Comment: Also, are you launching these processes from a single thread, or multiple threads?  If multiple, how are you incrementing `itemId`?

Comment: @dbc It is very possible that the Process ID is getting reused.  This loop occurs hundreds, or even thousands of times which leads me to think I need to remove items from my `ConcurrentBag` (or switch to `ConcurrentDictionary`).  They are being launched from a single thread.  Also, the `itemId` is a primary key from a database referring to the item to be processed.

Comment: @NedStoyanov I am utilizing an image processing toolkit that recommends using different processes so that the any resources the toolkit is using are released when each process terminates.

Comment: Without a complete code example, it's impossible to comment precisely. You certainly should not depend on the `Id` value as a unique identifier for the process over time (though it is when the process is running). But you haven't actually included any code here that would throw an exception when the `Id` and/or other values are the same, nor have you even given us the actual exception information as needed (i.e. the exception type, message, and full stack trace). If you want help, please provide [a _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the other details.

Comment: @PeterDuniho There really isn't much more to the code. There's a loop that calls `LaunchProc` as long as there aren't more than X instances already running. I suppose there is `proc_ErrorDataReceived`, but it doesn't modify `OutputData` so I didn't include it. The exception is simply a JSON parsing issue that tells me I have unexpected characters my `OutputData` (specifically the start brace of the next object). The only place I'm appending to my `OutputData` is in `proc_OutputDataReceived`. I've made changes given that the Process ID may be reused and hopefully that will fix my issue.

Comment: Clearing the `OutputData` in `proc_Exited` didn't work.  I'm still getting data appended more than once for a given Process Id.  I'm going to add some logging for troubleshooting, but anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: @dbc Ultimately, the reused Process ID was the issue.  I reworked the way I was storing my `OutputData` and the problem has not returned.

Comment: @JimBillig - shall I make that an answer then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of a Process [can get reused‌​](https://superuser.com/questions/636497/does-windows-7-reuse-process-ids).  Therefore I recommend not using the process ID as an identifier after the process has exited.

Instead, you could use your `itemId` as an identifier, associating the process output with it and encapsulating the process and `itemId` in some container, for instance (tested lightly, seems OK):

```
public class ProcessExitedEventArgs<TKey> : EventArgs
{
    public ProcessExitedEventArgs(TKey key, string[] output)
    {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Output = output;
    }

    public TKey Key { get; private set; }
    public string[] Output { get; private set; }
}

public delegate void ProcessExitedEventHandler<TKey>(object sender, ProcessExitedEventArgs<TKey> e);

public class ProcessLauncher<TKey>
{
    public string FileName { get; private set; }
    public string Arguments { get; private set; }
    public TKey Key { get; private set; }

    object locker = new object();
    readonly List<string> output = new List<string>();
    Process process = null;
    bool launched = false;

    public ProcessLauncher(string fileName, string arguments, TKey key)
    {
        this.FileName = fileName;
        this.Arguments = arguments;
        this.Key = key;
    }

    public event ProcessExitedEventHandler<TKey> Exited;

    public bool Start()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (launched)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            launched = true;
            process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            process.Exited += new EventHandler(proc_Exited);
            process.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;
            process.ErrorDataReceived += proc_ErrorDataReceived;
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = FileName;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments;
            try
            {
                var started = process.Start();

                process.BeginErrorReadLine();
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                return started;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                process.Dispose();
                process = null;
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    void proc_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            // Fill in as appropriate.
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Error data received: {0}", e.Data));
        }
    }

    void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data == null)
            return;
        lock (locker)
        {
            output.Add(e.Data);
        }
    }

    void proc_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            var exited = Exited;
            if (exited != null)
            {
                exited(this, new ProcessExitedEventArgs<TKey>(Key, output.ToArray()));
                // Prevent memory leaks by removing references to listeners.
                Exited -= exited;
            }
        }
        var process = Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.process, null);
        if (process != null)
        {
            process.OutputDataReceived -= proc_OutputDataReceived;
            process.ErrorDataReceived -= proc_ErrorDataReceived;
            process.Exited -= proc_Exited;
            process.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

(This class also makes sure the process is disposed.)  Then use it like:

```
    public void LaunchProc(int itemId)
    {
        var launcher = new ProcessLauncher<int>("someapp.exe", "/id=" + itemId, itemId);
        launcher.Exited += launcher_Exited;
        launcher.Start();
    }

    void launcher_Exited(object sender, ProcessExitedEventArgs<int> e)
    {
        var itemId = e.Key;
        var output = e.Output;

        // Process output and associate it to itemId.
    }
```

Comment: In your `proc_OutputDataReceived` event, you merely add the item with the associated data.  I guess one thing I couldn't determine is whether `proc_OutputDataReceived` would be called more than once for a given process.  Is it possible for `proc_OutputDataReceived` to be called more than once, possibly depending on the length of the output data?

Comment: [`proc_OutputDataReceived`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is called for each line the launched process writes to standard output.  What the launcher does is to collect all the output lines from the launched process, and when it exits, pass all of them to the event listener.  If, for instance, they all form a single JSON object, the listener could do `var token = JToken.Parse(string.Join("", e.Output));`.  In your case your process only outputs a single line, but this code doesn't assume that.